# Blanket implementation for `der::asn1::SetOfVec` not recognized by compiler?

Tags: rust

I want to DER encode a nested data structure using the [der crate](https://docs.rs/der/latest/der/index.html) of the RustCrypto project. I have a `Vec` of `SetOfVec`s. There should be a blanket implementation of `der::Encode` for `SetOfVec`, but the compiler does not recognize it:

```rust
// Add this to Cargo.toml:
// ...
// [dependencies]
// der = { version = "0.6", features = ["alloc", "oid"]}

// main.rs:

use der::{DecodeValue, Encode, Header, Reader, Sequence};
use der::asn1::{ObjectIdentifier, SetOfVec};

struct NestedType(Vec<SetOfVec<ObjectIdentifier>>);

impl<'a> DecodeValue<'a> for NestedType {
    fn decode_value<R: Reader<'a>>(reader: &mut R, header: Header) -> der::Result<Self> {
        Ok(reader.decode()?)
    }
}

impl<'a> Sequence<'a> for NestedType {
    fn fields<F, T>(&self, field_encoder: F) -> der::Result<T>
        where
            F: FnOnce(&[&dyn Encode]) -> der::Result<T>,
    {
        // This works
        // (the following 3 lines are just for comparison with the failing case)
        let encoder1 = SetOfVec::<ObjectIdentifier>::new();
        let encoder2 = SetOfVec::<ObjectIdentifier>::new();
        field_encoder(&[&encoder1, &encoder2])?;


        // This doesn't work
        let mut refs: Vec<&SetOfVec<ObjectIdentifier>> = Vec::new();
        for rdn in self.0.iter() {
            refs.push(rdn);
        }
        field_encoder(refs.as_slice())
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

The compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:33:23
   |
33 |         field_encoder(refs.as_slice())
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Encode`, found struct `SetOfVec`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&dyn Encode]`
              found reference `&[&SetOfVec<der::asn1::ObjectIdentifier>]`
```

As the `Encode` trait is implemented for `SetOfVec`, there should be no error. What's the problem here?

Comment: `&[&dyn Trait]` and `&[&T]` are not compatible even if `T: Trait` since references to trait objects are fat pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler needs more info. The following code creates a `Vec<&dyn Encode>` with the references pointing to the `SetOfVec`s in the original `Vec`. This should also solve the memory allocation issue, that @Chayim Friedman mentioned (please correct me, if I'm wrong):

```rust
impl<'a> Sequence<'a> for NestedType {
    fn fields<F, T>(&self, field_encoder: F) -> der::Result<T>
        where
            F: FnOnce(&[&dyn Encode]) -> der::Result<T>,
    {
        let mut refs: Vec<&dyn Encode> = Vec::new();
        for rdn in self.0.iter() {
            refs.push(rdn);
        }
        field_encoder(refs.as_slice())
    }
}
```